# ArgumentException was unhandled. The rectangle is too large or too small for this resource

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to create a collision detection method for a simple XNA racing game, for which I am using [this tutorial](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/extracting-texture-data) on how to extract texture data. What I'm trying to do is to check if any of the colors in that area of the texture are blue (which is the color of the walls on my racing track). However, I keep getting the error in the title. Can anyone explain to me why this happens?

code:

```
    public bool Collision()
    {
        int width = arrow.Width; //arrow is the name of my "car" texture (it's an arrow)
        int height = arrow.Height;
        int xr = (int)x; // x is the x position of my arrow
        int yr = (int)y; // y is the y position of my arrow
        Color[] rawData = new Color[width * height];
        Rectangle extractRegion = new Rectangle(xr, yr, width, height);
        track.GetData<Color>(0, extractRegion, rawData, 0, width * height); //error occurs here
        Color[,] rawDataAsGrid = new Color[height, width];
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < width; column++)
            {
                rawDataAsGrid[row, column] = rawData[row * width + column];
            }
        }
        for (int x1 = (int)x; x1 < width; x1++)
        {
            for (int y1 = (int)y; y1 < height; y1++)
            {
                if (rawDataAsGrid[x1, y1] == Color.Blue)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

edit: I got it working!

Comment: Can you add this method to code sample: track.GetData<Color>(params...)

Comment: How did you get it working? Do you not need further assistance? Can we delete the question now?

Answer (score 0):

Your rawData is not of sufficient length to receive the data you attempt to get with the GetData() method.

Change this line:

```
Color[] rawData = new Color[width * height];
```

into:

```
Color[] rawData = new Color[track.Width * track.Height];
```

And that should do it. Hope it helps!